# useffect doesnt run when give dependency obtain from useQuery

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

i have created custom hoook in react and used react query inside specifically useQuery now the problem is every time when i used this run Query function inside other component which actuallly update the state and re-render the whole custom hook and this re-rendering causing useQuery to run and thus useffect should also run which is not running why is it so i have tried many thing but it doesnt work

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { auth } from "../pages/ap-client/api";
import { getToken } from "../components/lib";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isrunQuery, setIsRunQuery] = useState(false);
  console.log("re-render");
  const { data, isSuccess } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["loginUser"],
    queryFn: auth.currentUser,
    enabled: true
    cacheTime: 0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("inside useffect ");
    if (data) {
      setUser(data?.response);
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data?.response));
    }
  }, [isSuccess]);
  const runQuery = () => setIsRunQuery(!isrunQuery);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser, runQuery }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext);

export default useUser;
```

`i ma expecting that usefeewct will run whever there is hit and by useQuery and thus give data`

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in this code? Are you sure that isSuccess have been changed?

Comment: Please use punctuation.